# Giving the end user the oppertunity to discard a default property setting in a user control

Tags: wpf, vb.net, user-controls, dependency-properties

I've been developing a wpf user control as a means of increasing my own knowledge and also because it will be of use to me in later projects.  Essentially it's a data navigator control looking not dissimilar to the image below.

[image]

Each button has a default image associated with it which the end user can replace if they so wish, achieved with the following code;

```
Private Shared ReadOnly DefaultFirstImage As ImageSource = New BitmapImage(New Uri("pack://application:,,,/DataNavigator;component/Images/first16.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))

'''////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
''' <summary>   Gets or sets the image first. </summary>
'''
''' <value> The image first. </value>
'''////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

<Description("The image used to represent navigating to the first record in the records collection"), Category("Navigation Button Images")>
Public Property ImageFirst() As ImageSource
    Get
        Return DirectCast(GetValue(ImageFirstProperty), ImageSource)
    End Get
    Set(value As ImageSource)
        SetValue(ImageFirstProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property



''' <summary>   The image first property. </summary>
Public Shared ReadOnly ImageFirstProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ImageFirst", GetType(ImageSource), GetType(DataNavigator), New UIPropertyMetadata(DefaultFirstImage))
```

The navigation buttons also have a text property which by default is set to an empty string but which can be customised by the end user.

Now I'd like to add one last customisation to this, give the end user the freedom to have no default image at all and simply text instead.  I'm thinking along the lines of a Boolean dependency property (lets say called RemoveFirstButtonImage ) with a default value of false which when checked would remove the image and set some default text instead.

I've done some playing about....

```
Public Shared ReadOnly RemoveDefaultFirstImageProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("RemoveDefaultFirstImage", GetType(Boolean), GetType(DataNavigator), New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(False, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, New PropertyChangedCallback(AddressOf OnRemoveDefaultFirstImageChanged)))

'''////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
''' <summary>
''' Gets or sets a value indicating whether the hide Template button is
''' shown.
''' </summary>
'''
''' <value> true if show hide Template button, false if not. </value>
'''////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

<Description("Set the visibility of the Template button on the Navigator Control"), Category("Navigator Buttons Default Image Visibility")>
Public Property RemoveDefaultFirstImage As Boolean
    Get
        Return CBool(GetValue(RemoveDefaultFirstImageProperty))
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        SetValue(RemoveDefaultFirstImageProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property

Private Shared Sub OnRemoveDefaultFirstImageChanged(ByVal d As DependencyObject, ByVal e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    Dim dn As DataNavigator = CType(d, DataNavigator)
    Dim bln As Boolean = (CType(e.NewValue, Boolean))
    If bln Then
        dn.DefaultFirstImage = New BitmapImage(New Uri("pack://application:,,,/DataNavigator;component/Images/first16.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
    Else
        DataNavigator.DefaultFirstImage = Nothing
    End If

End Sub
```

However there is an issue with the definition of the DefaultFirstImage Property.

Clearly it should no longer be shared and I suspect it should be public and have both a setter and getter  but is this all that needs to be done to achieve my desired result (I've left out adding default text but That's easy enough) or is there something else that I may have overlooked?

Thanks

Comment: You're setting dn.DefaultFirstImage and in the else case DataNavigator.DefaultFirstImage. Is that on purpose?

Comment: No it's not. Logically it should be dn in both cases. Currently ingellisense promts to change dn to DataNavigator.  That I presume is related to the need to refine the DefaultFirstImage property and possibly other things, hence the question.